# How to target a Font Awesome 5 svg icon in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome

It renders after the page loads but I have no idea how I can target that. It's wrapped in an anchor tag and I tried to set the z-index of that anchor tag to like 9999 so it's goes above the icon and I can target that but it's not working either.

```
 <nav class="menu">
        <div class="icon-list">
          <a class="highlight" href="#szolgáltatásaim"><i class="far fa-bell"></i><span>Szolgáltatásaim</span></a>
          <a class="highlight" href="#rólam"><i class="far fa-user"></i><span>Rólam</span></a>
          <a class="highlight" href="#munkáim"
          ><i class="far fa-folder-open"></i><span>Munkáim</span></a>
        <a class="highlight" href="#oktatás">
        <i class="fas fa-chalkboard"></i><span>Oktatás</span></a>
        <a class="highlight" href="#árak"
        ><i class="far fa-bookmark"></i><span>Árak</span></a >
          <a class="highlight" href="#marketing"
            ><i class="far fa-lightbulb"></i><span>Marketing</span></a>

          <a class="highlight" href="#üzenet"
            ><i class="far fa-envelope"></i><span>Üzenet</span></a>
          </div>
       </nav>
```

Comment: It is quite unclear to me what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I have a hamburger icon at top left. When you click it it has an animation and goes to an X and a menu appears at the top. I added an event listener to the body so if you click on it the menu dissapears and the hamburger icon goes back to normal. But the problem is if you click on the font awesome icons the hamburger icon changes back to normal while the menu stays. So I want to target the font awesome icons and exclude them from the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question needs more details so we can help you better. That being said, if you're trying to target multiple elements use class. If you're trying to target one specific element use ID. For this to work you'll need to add such properties to your `<i>` icons in your html code. Here's an example snippet. Is this what you need?

```js
function changeAll() {
 var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.far,.fas'); // To target multiple elements use class
 for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].style.color = "red";
 }
}
function changeBell() {
  document.getElementById("bell").style.color = "green"; // To target one specific element use ID
}
```

```html
<script async src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0f49cf42f1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="menu">
  <div class="icon-list">
    <a class="highlight" href="#szolgáltatásaim"><i class="far fa-bell" id="bell"></i><span>Szolgáltatásaim</span></a>
    <a class="highlight" href="#rólam"><i class="far fa-user"></i><span>Rólam</span></a>
    <a class="highlight" href="#munkáim"><i class="far fa-folder-open"></i><span>Munkáim</span></a>
    <a class="highlight" href="#oktatás">
      <i class="fas fa-chalkboard"></i><span>Oktatás</span></a>
    <a class="highlight" href="#árak"><i class="far fa-bookmark"></i><span>Árak</span></a >
          <a class="highlight" href="#marketing"
            ><i class="far fa-lightbulb"></i><span>Marketing</span></a>

    <a class="highlight" href="#üzenet"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i><span>Üzenet</span></a>
  </div>
</nav>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="changeAll()">Change color of all icons</button>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="changeBell()">Change color of bell only</button>
```

Comment: Sorry if my question is hard to understand. I know how to select elements but the problem is with font awesome 5 (javascript version) it renders the icons as svgs after the site is loaded so I can't target it and if I click on that icon the target element is not the i but the svg that rendered after the site loaded. I checked and that svg elements has classes like .svg-inline--fa and .fa-bell too but I can't target these in javascript. I think it's becouse it's renders after the site is loaded.